# await is only valid in async function discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was making music play bot for my server but i think i did something wrong.
I was doing like that [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_QKOKnRzZ8) but i'm getting `await is only valid in async function` error

```
module.exports = (msg) => {   
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

if (!msg.member.voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('Please Connect to a voice channel');

if (msg.guild.me.voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('Im in another channel');

if(!args[1]) return msg.channel.send('no URL no music');

let validate = await ytdl.validateURL(args[1]);

if(!validate) return msg.channel.send('Please input a valid url following the command');

let info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);

let connection = await msg.member.voiceChannel.join();

let dispatcher = await connection.play(ytdl(args[1], {filet: 'audioonly'}));

msg.channel.send(`Now playing : ${info.title}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all, the function in which you use `await` needs to be asynchronous (`async`)

```js
module.exports = async (msg) => {   
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

if (!msg.member.voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('Please Connect to a voice channel');

if (msg.guild.me.voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('Im in another channel');

if(!args[1]) return msg.channel.send('no URL no music');

let validate = await ytdl.validateURL(args[1]);

if(!validate) return msg.channel.send('Please input a valid url following the command');

let info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);

let connection = await msg.member.voiceChannel.join();

let dispatcher = await connection.play(ytdl(args[1], {filet: 'audioonly'}));

msg.channel.send(`Now playing : ${info.title}`);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to SO. If an answer solves your question you should accept it, this lets others know the question has been answered and also lets people looking for answers know what worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the "async" keyboard in your function, so: module.exports = async (msg) => {

Comment: Thanks dude! Thanks a lot!