# when i launch my bot discord i have an error and i can't find how to fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

hello i'm trying to code my first bot and especially a command for it to give its ping and that of the API but when i launch the bot i have this error and i don't know how to fix it

```
        waiting = await message.channel.send("Je calcule le ping...").catch(console.error);
                  ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

currently the code is this :

```
const Discord = require ("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    execute(bot, message, args){
        message.delete().catch(console.error);

        waiting = await message.channel.send("Je calcule le ping...").catch(console.error);

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor("Latence du bot & de l'api discord.js", bot.user.avatarURL)
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setTitle("pong !")
        .addField("**CactusBot :**", "> `" + `${bot.ws.ping}` + "ms`", true)
        .addField("**API :**", "> `" + Math.round(bot.ping) + "ms`", true)
        .setTimestamp(message.createdAt)
        .setFooter("Nuptay | demandé par @" + message.author.tag, bot.user.avatarURL)
        waiting.edit(pingEmbed).catch(console.error);
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

(yes I am French)

thank you for your answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [await is only valid in async function discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924701/await-is-only-valid-in-async-function-discord-js)

Answer (score 1):

As the error states you are using `await` inside a non-async function.

Write a separate `async` function for your code and export that function:

```
const execute = async (bot, message, args) => {
  // your code with await
}

module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  execute,
}
```

[Check the discord guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-the-bot-file)

[More information about async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: thank you for your quick response

now I have this error :

`    execute async (bot, message, args) {
            ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'async'`

Comment: Oh, I've updated my answer according to this.

Comment: ok thanks, I had errors afterwards but I managed to correct them and do you know how to make it give me the ping of the API as well because now it tells me "NaNms"

Comment: NaN means "not a number", try to log the information you need first to see what inside.

Comment: hm how can I do that ?

Comment: Just `console.log(bot)`, but I'm not familiar with discord.js.